# Event listener not working in IOS - Inappbrowser phonegap

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins, inappbrowser

I am using latest version of cordova(version-5). I use Inappbrowser plugin in phongap. It works perfectly with android but not working in ios. Tried all methods, don't know what is missing. Please help.
Thank you.

```
var ref = '';    
$j('#gotoCheckoutOpenInAppBrowsr').click(function(){
    var chckOutURL = $j(this).attr('data-checkoutURL');
    ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open(chckOutURL, '_self', 'location=no');
    ref.addEventListener('loadstart', function(event) {
    alert('ka');
    ref.executeScript({ code: " var xyz = 10" });
});
ref.addEventListener('loaderror', function(event) {
  $j('#ajax_loading').hide();
  alert('Please try again.');
  ref.close();
});
ref.addEventListener('loadstop', function(event) {
 var loop = setInterval(function() {
 ref.executeScript({ code: " xyz " }, function(values){
    var name = values[0];
    if ( name == 20 ) {
      $j('#ajax_loading').hide();
      clearInterval( loop );
      ref.close();
    }
  });
  }, 1000);
});
});
```

Comment: @jcesarmobile: Hello, code added, let me know if any error in this.

Comment: don't use InAppBrowser with _self option, if you use _self you load the website on the cordova webview, if you use _blank you load it on the InAppBrowser, if you use _system you load it on the system browser. The event listeners should only work with _blank option, not sure why it works on android for you, but it shouldn't

Comment: Thank you. I check it with _blank, but _self is working fine with android.

Comment: @jcesarmobile Thank you, It works for me but in loadstop event I use setInterval, in setInterval executeScript not works. can you provide solution?